# React Query invalidateQueries does not set loading to true

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm using the `useMutation` hook to delete the entity and the `useQuery` hook to load the entities from the api as follows:

```js
const { mutate: $delete } = useMutation(deleteDiscipline, {
  onSuccess: () => {
    queryClient.invalidateQueries('disciplines')
  },
})

const { isLoading, data: disciplines } = useQuery(['disciplines', filter], getFilteredDisciplines)
```

I rely on the `isLoading` field to display the loading status bar.
It works when I trigger refetch by switching tabs or changing the filter (query depends on `filter` state).
But when I call `queryClient.invalidateQueries` the api call is made and data is updated, but the `isLoading` field stays `true` for the entire refetching time.

Awaiting for the invalidation didn't help either:

```js
const { mutate: $delete } = useMutation(deleteDiscipline, {
  onSuccess: async () => {
    await queryClient.invalidateQueries('disciplines')
  },
})
```

How can I detect the request occurs (including all the triggers like query invalidations and others that I haven't encounter yet)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`isLoading` is only true for a hard-loading state, where you have no `data` to display. Since react-query embraces stale-while-revaliate, it will give you stale data while at the same time doing a background refetch. So your status in that case is still `success`, with `isSuccess` being true, and `data` being available.

`isFetching` is an additional flag that is always true when a request is in-flight. This is true for the first loading as well as for all background updates.

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to use the `isFetching` field instead of the `isLoading` for subsequent fetches.